# Retrieve ID from Map to use as a field update on Lookup field

Tags: apex

I'm not a full time programmer, so coding can sometimes get the best of me. We have a custom process where we are creating cases from a web form (not web to case). The form is able to write to SFDC, but for some reason the contact field is not being populated. I tried writing a class that will take the webemail and search for a contact ID using that email, so that I can then populate the lookup field for contact. I'm currently hard coding the value, but would like to get the value from my "conid" map and apply it to the field. Thank you in advance.

```
public static void onBeforeInsert(List<Case> trgNew) {


     {
         Set<ID> caseids = new Set<ID>();
         Set<String> con = new Set<String>();
         for (Case ca : trgNew)
             if (ca.opportunity__c != null) {
                 caseids.add(ca.Opportunity__c);
                 con.add(ca.suppliedemail);
             }

         Map<Id,Opportunity> oppdetails = new Map <Id, Opportunity>([Select ID, Agency_Trading_Desk__c, Client_Services_Owner__c From Opportunity Where ID in:caseids]);
         Map<Id,Contact> conid = new Map <Id, Contact>([Select ID From contact WHERE email in : con]);


         for (Case cs : trgNew) {

             if (!oppdetails.isEmpty()) {

                 cs.client_services_owner__c =  oppdetails.get(cs.Opportunity__c).Client_services_Owner__c;
                         }

             if(conid.size() > 0)
             {
                 cs.contactid= '0032A00002SyklB'; //would like to pull ID from conid map here, so value can be dynamic

             }

             if(conid.isEmpty() && !oppdetails.isempty()){
                 cs.accountid=oppdetails.get(cs.Opportunity__c).Agency_Trading_Desk__c;
             }
         }
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your contact map needs be keyed on email string rather than Id, since email is the only contact-related data point you have in your cases.

You would populate your contact map like this:

```
Map<String, Contact> conMap = new Map<String, Contact>();
for (Contact con : [SELECT Email FROM Contact WHERE Email IN :con]) {
    conMap.put(con.email, con);
}
```

(Note that SOQL automatically includes the Id field so you don't need to specify it explicitly.)

Then when you iterate through your cases, you can retrieve the contact Id like this:

```
cs.ContactId = conMap.get(cs.SuppliedEmail).Id;
```

Be sure to review the [Map methods documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_map.htm) especially `get`, `put` and `containsKey` methods.

As a side note: your naming convention can be confusing.  Example: you are adding opportunity Ids to your `caseids` set, so it would be better to call it `oppIds`.

Comment: Thanks for your help! The class is now working!  I've always used ID sets, so was a bit off as I'm still learning. I totally get how you linked the contact ID to the SuppliedEmail. It works similar to how I was linking to the opportunity field. I tried retrieving the contact value similar to how i was retrieving the opp values, but I kept getting null pointer exception, which is now clear to me since that field was never populated. I really appreciate the knowledge you've given me with your outlined response. I have renamed my aliases to align with the sets I'm working with. Thanks again!